# What are the main differences between the Catholic Popes and the Mormon Prophets?

Tags: catholicism, lds, papacy, comparative-christianity

I ask this question, as a Catholic, because Mormonism is hierarchical in structure and has a lot of similarities with Catholicism, although seemingly they are superficial as in being surface impretions but I digress.

**This question, and the answers, will help shed light on a lot of misunderstandings, I think.** Taking something most of us are familiar with, like the Pope (and these days he is quite popular) and contrast him with a leader not so well known which is the Prophet.

> **The Specific Elements I Expect in the Answers :**
>
> On Church Management in General
>
> **(1)** If both claim the Petrine Seat(by succession or?).
>
> **(2)** If both have a College of Bishops/"Highest Teachers"  in union with the Pope or Prophet.
>
> **(3)** If both have universal jurisdiction as universal pastors of their respective churches. Meaning that they can operate in all
>   churches as if they were the head of those individual churches, no
>   need to appeal to the locals.
>
> **(4)** If both are completely immune from stepping down from the office unless it is their own decision to step down.
>
> **(5)** If believers are encouraged to listen to the leader above any other in the hierarchy in case of disagreement between the leader and others
>   on none dogmatic issues, as well as disagreements outside of the Church on politics for example.
>
> On Infallibility
>
> **(6)** If both claim to be infallible under certain conditions(if so what are they?) by virtue of their office in the eyes of God.

Of course if the two views differ, the one answering must explain where they differ. It does not need to be overly detailed, **one  authoritative official reference for both sides per point will suffice.**

Comment: The problem with comparison questions is that it severely limits the number of people who can answer them.  I can answer for the LDS side of the Q, but cannot on the Catholic side.  Perhaps you should ask this as two separate qustions, inviting in each that only one denomination answer?  You'll likely get better results.

Comment: Good idea, I'll do that.

Comment: Do we want an answer according to one denomination, or both?

Comment: @DestynationY I answered from the LDS side. If you know about the Catholic side, feel free to edit it in: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/63517/35930

Answer (score 2):

Note: My knowledge on Catholic beliefs is spotty. If anyone Catholic wants to go ahead and fill in the gaps, go ahead. I do not intend to offend any Catholics with it.

When you prophets, I will assume you are talking about the President of the Church, not the other non-president prophets (i.e. members of the Quorum of the Twelve Apostles).

Before I go on to your six questions, I would like to note the main theological difference: The Pope claims to be able to receive no revelation, but rather is making decisions based on what he thinks is best, and according to scripture. The prophet claims to use both scripture and revelation from God (hence the name) instead of his own decision making.

Anyways, to your six questions.

> (1) If both claim the Petrine Seat(by succession or?).

They both claim to succeed Peter in being the head of the true church of christ, in a documented line of succession from Peter to themselves.

> (2) If both have a College of Bishops/"Highest Teachers" in union with the Pope or Prophet.

I do not know about the Pope, but in the LDS Church there are (usually) 14 other prophets in addition to *the* prophet. These prophets are also Apostles, seers, and revelators.

> (3) If both have universal jurisdiction as universal pastors of their
>   respective churches. Meaning that they can operate in all churches as
>   if they were the head of those individual churches, no need to appeal
>   to the locals.

I assume the Pope may do so. The Prophet has all the keys of this dispensation, including the leading of local congregations. He usually does not "usurp" local congregations though, since his main duty is being a prophet.

> (4) If both are completely immune from stepping down from the office unless it is their own decision to step down.

I do not know about the Pope. The prophet is subject to God, who can remove him from office if he attempts to lead the church astray (see Official Declaration 1). Additionally, he is subject to disciplinary council of the church if he commits a serious sin.

> (5) If believers are encouraged to listen to the leader above any other in the hierarchy in case of disagreement between the leader and others on none dogmatic issues, as well as disagreements outside of the Church on politics for example.

I assume this is true of the Pope. It is generally recognized in the LDS Church that the Prophet is more accurate than local leaders, though both try to stay in harmony with God (and therefore with each other, indirectly).

> (6) If both claim to be infallible under certain conditions(if so what are they?) by virtue of their office in the eyes of God.

I'm not sure about the Pope. For the LDS Church, see [What does the LDS Church teach about infallibility?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/63495/35930).

Comment: I will fill in some gaps later, but nice entry anyway.

Comment: I've proposed an edit.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the Prophet and the Pope is that the Prophet has authority to lead and direct the church, whereas the Pope does not.

**To be more specific:** The Prophet has the proper priesthood authority, as was given to Peter.

> 18 And I say also unto thee, That thou art Peter, and upon this rock I
>   will build my church; and the gates of hell shall not prevail against
>   it.
>
> 19 And I will give unto thee **the keys of the kingdom of heaven**: and
>   whatsoever thou shalt bind on earth shall be bound in heaven: and
>   whatsoever thou shalt loose on earth shall be loosed in heaven. [Matt 16:18-19](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/matt/16.18-19#p17)

In that act, Christ gave Peter authority to lead and direct the church. It was then established that the head of the church would be chosen from one of the twelve apostles. A pattern of determining whom should fill vacancies in the Twelve was also established:

> 22 Beginning from the baptism of John, unto that same day that he was
>   taken up from us, must one be ordained to be a witness with us of his
>   resurrection.
>
> 23 And they appointed two, Joseph called Barsabas, who was surnamed
>   Justus, and Matthias.
>
> 24 And they prayed, and said, Thou, Lord, which knowest the hearts of
>   all men, shew whether of these two thou hast chosen,
>
> 25 That he may take part of this ministry and apostleship, from which
>   Judas by transgression fell, that he might go to his own place.
>
> 26 And they gave forth their lots; and the lot fell upon Matthias; and
>   he was numbered with the eleven apostles. [Acts 1:21-26](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/acts/1.22-26?lang=eng&clang=eng#p20)

In the years that followed, all the apostles were martyred. The vacancies in the Twelve were not filled, the line of apostolic succession was broken, and those keys were lost.

It was not until the time of Joseph Smith that those priesthood keys were [restored to the earth](https://www.lds.org/topics/restoration-of-the-gospel?lang=eng), when Peter, James, and John appeared in the flesh to Joseph Smith and Oliver Cowdery, and conferred upon them the Holy Priesthood of God.

Without the priesthood, and the keys of revelation, the Pope cannot commune with the Father, and has no authority to speak on his behalf.

Comment: This does not highlight any differences

Comment: And it is quite biased and historically inaccurate. If you really must know, you could start from Pope Francis and trace back the succession to finally end at St. Peter. We have all the documents. The first successor was Linus who according to tradition is briefly mentioned by name in the NT. The Church of Rome has held the presidency as St. Ignatius says in 110AD. Mormonism simply cannot rival us in history, it is, put bluntly, a heresy so alien that it cannot be associated with the title Christian. But I digress, you'll need to be less subjective next time around.

Comment: From someone with over 6k reputation, I'm very surprised to see such a biased, un-referenced answer.

Comment: @Destynation - I agree, but your comment falls into much the same category.

Comment: @DestynationY I'm familiar with the Catholic lines of apostolic succession (Roman and Orthodox). The line was broken at Peter. Linus was a bishop, not an apostle, nor was he a member of the twelve. No doubt he held the priesthood, but he could not have received the apostolic keys to the kingdom of heaven, ergo his authority was limited in his office as a bishop. The apostles were unable to fill the vacancies in the twelve as they did in Acts Ch. 1. What happened as a result was the slow transition into the great apostasy.

Comment: Obiz, I wasn't trying to be neutral since it was more of a rant and I prefaced it with "if you really must know". But if I were to answer the question, and not rant in the comments, I would be more neutral no doubt.

Comment: ShemSeger, to continue my rant. What you said is kind of ridiculous, like are we to believe that the highest Mormon authorities are Apostles yet cannot point to a succession? Come on. It isn't called APOSTOLIC succession just for show, it hands over apostolic authority. Every ordained minister of the Church, in the clergy, has apostolic succession. But only the successor who was simultaniously given the apostolic calling AND the keys can be the Supreme Pontiff. The binding and loosing of the Apostles and their successors depends on those keys. Given by succesion, which you have none of.

Comment: @DestynationY The prophet does not choose his successor. God does. When there is a vacancy in the quorum of the twelve it is the duty of the apostles to determine whom God would call to fill that vacancy. When a prophet dies, typically the most senior apostle takes his place, but this calling must be sustained by the whole church. This takes place during the solemn assembly, which you can view online actually, there was a solemn assembly at the last general conference of the church to sustain Russell M Nelson as the new President of the Church.

Comment: We kind of have the same thing, 200 princes of the Church aka Cardinals get together and lock themselves in the Basilica of St. Peter and begin to vote. It's called a conclave, and it can last from a few moments to even weeks. But them electing someone to the office of St. Peter wouldn't have any effect unless there was an actual succession. Even the whole conclave thing wouldn't be possible if it wasn't for the previous Popes declaring infallibly that successions *can* be done this way. My point is, both of claim succession but only one Church has the history to back it up. *Rome sweet home*

Comment: @DestynationY Your claim of an unbroken line of succession is historically suspect at best.  Historical records from the early days of the Church are alarmingly spotty, and assuming an unbroken succession lasted as long as the late 14th century, it was definitely broken at that point, during the "Western schism," in which two Popes, contemporaneously ordained by the Cardinals, both claimed the true apostolic succession and both excommunicated one another, among other things.  This was finally resolved by the Cardinals electing a yet another new pope and glossing over all the messiness.

Comment: The textbook example of the worst schism I know of is when  3 Bishops claimed to be the Pope at the same time, I think that's what you're talking about. And all of this started because the true Pope, that of Rome as per usual, was an antipope which is a theological term. Suffice it to say that he wasn't, theologians were rounded up to discover whether the succession was valid and the answer was yes, end of debate. The other popes however were antipopes and stepped down. The fact that we solved the problem shows God is with us. **Whereas you think no succession at all is somehow an argument.**

Comment: Sorry I meant "and all of this started because the true Pope, that of Rome as per usual, was ACCUSED of being an antipope which is a theological term. Anyway, even if I grant you your premise of our successions being on thin ice our case would still be better than yours since we actually have a succession to appeal to whereas you state black on white that you have not been ordained by the Apostles but instead that Joseph Smith supposedly assissted by God fixed the problem. It just false really, it's special pleading.

Comment: @DestynationY I can imagine Christ's disciples had to deal with a lot of this same talk when speaking with the sadducees and pharisees about authority in the Church. Read [this](https://www.lds.org/topics/restoration-of-the-gospel?lang=eng).

Comment: I read some of the article, but it essentially false into the same fallacy. Special pleading. You cannot compare the situation of Jesus, the Apostles and the Jews with that of the Mormons. Jesus acknowledged that the Jews had ordinary authority and Caiaphas even prophecies of Jesus' death for Israel by virtue of him being High Priest even though he is quite evil. But Jesus also points out that his own succession is superior to that of the Jewish authorities, because he is the Son of David Messiah and therefore has ultimate authority. This he hands to the Apostles and sends them out. Succesion.